# Will my SSL keys be removed if I re-install apache2?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, vps

I already have my csr and key. But I tried to configure `apache` server and messed everything there. If I am going to re-install it again do I need to have a new csr and key to activate https or can I still use it again? if that's possible.

How can I re-install apache2? give me the command line code for it? I am really new with it. I'm working on my VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your keys should ideally have been installed in `/etc/ssl/private` but is depended on the command you ran to create them and or the directory you were in at the time. Apache would have been consigured to reference them in the relevant location.  `apt-get purge` will not remove these keys.

To be safe, back them up and then do an `apt-get purge apache2`